# Display result of a selected choice in echo (PHP form)

Tags: php, javascript, forms, echo

I have a form with a table that I use to select from a series of radio buttons.

(Explanation: The table works as a series of buttons, by using onClick commands, for example:

```
...
        <td onClick="answer7()" background="images/button-bg7.png" width="100"><div align="center"><span class="style4">Activities</span></div></td>
          <td onClick="answer8()" background="images/button-bg8.png" width="100"><p align="center" class="style2">Suggestions/ Ideas</p>          </td>
          <td onClick="answer9()" background="images/button-bg9.png" width="100"><div align="center"><span class="style2">Repairs</span></div></td>
...
```

)

This selects from a series of hidden fields, essentially hidden Radio buttons (For example:

```
        <input type="hidden" name="RadioGroup1" value="Activities" id="RadioGroup1_6" />
Activities</label>
        <br />
        <label>
        <input type="hidden" name="RadioGroup1" value="Suggestions" id="RadioGroup1_7" />
Suggestions</label>
        <br />
        <label>
        <input type="hidden" name="RadioGroup1" value="Repairs" id="RadioGroup1_8" />
Repairs</label>
```

)

This has been tested and works well - the buttons in the table do, indeed, select the correct choices from the hidden radio fields.

Now, I want to construct a sentence further down the form that tells them which one they selected, for example "Please continue with your *selected choice* query below:"

I imagine I'll need to use Javascript, or jQuery, but can't think how to construct it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As a first comment it would be simpler if you would create one onClick handler for all these elements. When clicked grab the id attribute of your td (which you have to set of course), then you won't need the hidden fields and at the same time you have the choice the user made. Something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="myClick" id="Activities"> Press here </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="myClick" id="Repairs"> Press here aswell </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Althought it doesn't have to be the id attribute you change, you could use something else aswell. 
jQuery inspired:

```
$("td.myClick").click(function() { alert("You clicked: " + $(this).attr("id")); });
```

This should be a beginning of it, you can change the alert part to edit another div with jQuery (hint is to use the .html() function), it should be fairly straightforward. Please ask if you need more info.

Comment: OK, that could work. The reason that I went for hidden fields is that ,eventually, the form is going to be submitted to a database. Would this matter to the solution you proposed? Or, failing that, could the solution you proposed be modified to fit with my initial form? (Please forgive the n00b comments...!)

Comment: If you're going to submit this info to the db with the current form you will get all the hidden fields which i guess is not what you want? You could make an AJAX request to a page which adds the data as you wish to have it, or you can create the form on the fly with the data you gather and the submit it with an added submit button where the user is done. I would recommend doing the AJAX approach.

Comment: Actually, I do want the data from the hidden fields to be added - the only reason I hid them was because I wanted to design my own "radio buttons" (i.e. the table), rather than using the standard radio buttons. The data itself still needs to be collected (hence the onClick action setting the values of the hidden radio buttons). Does this make sense?

Comment: Do you want _all_ the hidden fields? Not just the ones the user selected? That would seem redundant.

Comment: Ooh, do you set the value of the hidden fields with what the user selected? Then you probably should leave the fields.